# Capture a key + mouse event JavaFx over a button

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I have implemented this skeleton code for executing a different action depending on what mouse button you click and how many clicks over a button.

```
Button button = new Button("Action!");
button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event){ 
    if(event.getButton().equals(MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
        if(event.getClickCount() == 2){
            System.out.println("Double click");
        }else if(event.getClickCount() == 1){
            System.out.println("Single click");
        }else{
            System.out.println("SUPER click");
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Secondary click");
    }
}              
});
```

I would like to capture a key (Ctrl for example) + mouse click event, so if the user clicks the button when the key is pressed, I can capture the key event inside the mouse event handler, in order to extend the possible actions. How could I perform that?

Comment: note that this makes the button not work with the keyboard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do it with:

```
if(event.isControlDown()){...}
```

for ctrl.
There are more methods like that (Alt,shift, ... )